# How do I make this shape in HTML?

Tags: html, css, shapes, css-shapes

I'm trying to make this shape in HTML/CSS, and I can't do it for the life of me. If anyone can give a heads-up, it would be much appreciated. Including JS also doesn't matter. If you can give the smallest nudge in the right direction, I would be grateful.
Thanks, here's the drawing.

[image: Shape]

Comment: Please include what you have tried.

Comment: A combination square div and a rectangle div? Where the rectangular div has `border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;` or something similar. Also the SVG route is an option.

Comment: [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial) or some hack with `border-radius`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to help us help you, please include a [minimal reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can give you a hand!

Comment: @thetechnician94 YT_Xaos Dudes I couldn't figure out how to do it, that's why I wrote the question. The most I can do is that image.

Comment: @JeswinSunsi You should have some attempt that you made prior to posting a question here. That is what we are looking for. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used vh and % units to make it responsive.Just a small code  and responsive as well.

#### This will work for u.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10%;
  padding-top: 40%;
  width: 40%;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 14% 14% 0 0;
}

p {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  padding-top: 10%;
  margin-top: -28%;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<p></p>
```

Comment: This looks super weird on small screens. https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpqog.jpg

Comment: @WebDevNoob well just  change the height and width of div as per your choice well my work was to make the code concise and readable i still edited my code and made some changes  in the dimensions

Answer (score 2):

one element solution:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
  background: black;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  transform:translateY(-20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Can't get much cleaner

Answer (score 1):

Create a couple of divs, one the width and height of the big bit, one a square with width that of the diameter of the semi circle.

Background of both black.

Big bit has border-radius something like 10%, play around to get what you want, on the top corners, 0 on the bottom corners.

Semi circle is a circle in fact, border radius 50%. Position absolute within the big bit.

Warning, sometimes border radius can give a not very smooth finish. If that’s a problem you could try an SVG, but your question stipulated HTML and CSS.

If you make the dimensions and positioning %s it will expand or contract to fit as required.

Answer (score 0):

**Just to complement the other answers* which went through `<div>` implementations using HTML/CSS, below is an SVG approach:

### SVG Implementation:

Can be created using many design tools such as Figma, Vectornator and Illustrator and exported as inline SVG-code. Or by typing out the coordinates and paths manually which is a pretty lengthy process. Press the blue <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> button below to see the results and test the responsiveness using the full page link:

```css
#Shape {
  position: absolute;
  --Width: 60%;
  --Height: 80%;
  width: var(--Width);
  height: var(--Height);
  top: calc(50% - var(--Height)/2);
  left: calc(50% - var(--Width)/2);
}
```

```html
<svg id="Shape" viewBox="0 0 374 381" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M248.434 46H334C356.092 46 374 63.9087 374 86V381H0V86C0 63.9087 17.9082 46 40 46H125.566C133.342 19.417 157.903 0 187 0C216.097 0 240.658 19.417 248.434 46Z" fill="rgba(30,28,33,1)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use standard css: border (mid span) and border-radius (left & right span). Please change the sizes if you want the logo smaller or larger.

```css
/* some default css so other css in your project will not interfere */
#logo span {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: black;
}
/* below the css for the logo */
#logo .l, #logo .r {
  width: 160px;
  height: 420px;
}
#logo .l {
  border-top-left-radius: 45px;
}
#logo .r {
  border-top-right-radius: 45px;
}
#logo .m {
  width: 0;
  height: 475px;
  border: 55px solid black;
  border-top-left-radius: 55px;
  border-top-right-radius: 55px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <span class="l"></span><span class="m"></span><span class="r"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: It breaks up on small screens. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJFND.jpg

Comment: Yep, that's because I took fixed dimensions as shown in the image. By using `@media`, the css width, height and border size can be adjusted for small, medium and large browser views. Another way for correct dimensions in each view is using the vw (not px) as size unit.